# Which is faster .exist or .value in a where clause?

Tags: sql-server, performance, xpath, xquery-sql

I am doing some crude benchmarks with the xml datatype of SQL Server 2008. I've seen many places where `.exist` is used in `where` clauses. I recently compared two queries though and got odd results.

```
select count(testxmlrid) from testxml
where Attributes.exist('(form/fields/field)[@id="1"]')=1
```

This query takes about 1.5 seconds to run, with no indexes on anything but the primary key(testxmlrid)

```
select count(testxmlrid) from testxml
where Attributes.value('(/form/fields/field/@id)[1]','integer')=1
```

This query on the otherhand takes about .75 seconds to run.

I'm using untyped XML and my benchmarking is taking place on a SQL Server 2008 Express instance. There are about 15,000 rows in the dataset and each XML string is about 25 lines long.

Are these results I'm getting correct? If so, why does everyone use `.exist`? Am I doing something wrong and `.exist` could be faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not counting the same things. Your `.exist` query `(form/fields/field)[@id="1"]` checks all occurrences of `@id` in the XML until it finds one with the value `1` and your `.value` query `(/form/fields/field/@id)[1]` only fetches the first occurrence of `@id`.

Test this:

```
declare @T table
(
  testxmlrid int identity primary key,
  Attributes xml
)

insert into @T values
('<form>
    <fields>
      <field id="2"/>
      <field id="1"/>
    </fields>
  </form>')

select count(testxmlrid) from @T
where Attributes.exist('(form/fields/field)[@id="1"]')=1

select count(testxmlrid) from @T
where Attributes.value('(/form/fields/field/@id)[1]','integer')=1
```

The `.exist` query count is 1 because it finds the `@id=1`in the second `field` node and the `.value` query count is 0 because it only checks the value for the first occurrence of `@id`.

An `.exist` query that only checks the value for the first occurrence of `@id` like your `.value` query would look like this.

```
select count(testxmlrid) from @T
where Attributes.exist('(/form/fields/field/@id)[1][.="1"]')=1
```

Comment: Does `exist()` not short-circuit as soon as it finds the first occurrence anyway?

Comment: @Yuck - Yes it does but in this case the `.exist` query is searching for the presence of `@id=1`. If the first occurrence if `@id` is something else than 1 it continues to search. The `.value` query looks at the value for the first occurrence of `@id` and does not continue searching if that values is not 1.

Answer (score 0):

The difference *could* come from your indexes.

A `PATH` index will boost performance of the `exist()` predicate on the `WHERE` clause, whereas a `PROPERTY` index will boost performance of the `value()` function.

Read:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522562.aspx